# How to say "To serve, not to be served" in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, idiom, grammar-choice, ecclesiastical-latin

I would like to know how to translate the phrase "To serve, not to be served" in Latin.
It doesn't have to be a word for word translation. But, I want to know the phrase that would give the impression I'm going for to a Latin native.

To serve, as in to give freely to help others.
Not be served, as in not depending on others to help you.

Comment: Tip: If you have a phrase that you know comes from the Bible, and you want to know how to say it in Latin, you can simply look it up in the [Vulgate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulgate), which is exactly where the top answer comes from, that's what the "VG" link means.

Comment: Thanks  for the tip :) I didn't know it came from the Bible when I wrote it, I didn't even know what Vulgate was. Now I do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Welcome to the site!

> **Non ministrari, sed ministrare** ([VG Mt 20,28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthaeus%2020%3A28&version=VULGATE))

Is a well-attested phrase with that exact meaning. It literally means *not to be served but to serve*. The context is Jesus in the Gospel of Matthew saying that He (the Son of man) came not to be served but to serve.

**Update:** it is (arguably) a common choice for mottos. Besides the American College of Greece (see comments), it is also the motto of [Wellesley College](https://www.wellesley.edu/) in MA, USA (among others) and at least six [recent catholic bishops](https://www.heraldry-wiki.com/heraldrywiki/index.php?title=Non_ministrari_sed_ministrare).

Comment: Oh my god!!!! Thank you!!!!! :) This is exactly the phrase they used. I just looked it up ;)

Comment: @AlexandrosKourtis, well, you are welcome. Now I'm curious who _they_ are... :)

Comment: Oh, it's the college I go to :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_College_of_Greece

Comment: It's funny, they even have it on their wiki page but I didn't see it before I posted the question here...

Comment: Curious that the American College of Greece has a Latin motto, and to make things worse, one that is a translation of a Greek original :)

Comment: Sebastian: Your observation is both ironic and smart! Nicely done.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest:

> **Servire, non Serviri**

Another option, based on a model from Cicero ("Esse quam videri" = "To be rather than to seem") is:

> **Servire quam Serviri**

Note that this final construction is somewhat elliptical.

A final option, which captures the sense rather than the literal meaning, is from Acts 20:35:

> **Beatius est magis dare, quam accipere.**

"It is better to give than to receive"

Comment: Thank you :) Even though @Rafael gave me the answer I was looking for, thank you for the alternatives. They are also great! I can use them instead, so I don't seem like a copycat ;)

Comment: Are you sure *serviri* works? As far as I know, *servire* goes with dative instead of accusative, so I'm not sure the passive infinitive does what it would do for a transitive verb.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I didn't think of that! I checked L&S and it looks like there's only one attested use of a passive *servire* (by Seneca the Younger), so it's probably not the best option.

Comment: @brianpck Interestingly, that attestation (*servis paucioribus serviri*) seems to be doubtful as well. Several editions of the text I found online had *servire*, and [here](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Of_Peace_of_Mind#IX.) it is translated as "to be the slaves of fewer slaves", which admittedly seems contorted. Ah, the simple stoic life, where you have only a few slaves ...!

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: This (servis paucioribus serviri.) looks like "You serve too few [of those about] to be served.". Then, that might be indirect, requiring future participle, "servituros esse", not passive infinitive, "serviri"?

Comment: @tony The context is, roughly, “Get used to getting by with less.” I see no indirect speech (no verbum dicendi/cogitandi), but note that, in any event, *servituros* means “about to serve,” not “about to be served.” (Remember *morituri te salutant* = “those about to die salute you” – that *mori* is a deponent verb makes not difference, by the way.)